# Sproutcore vs Cappuccino data model layer

Tags: cappuccino, sproutcore

I was going through cappuccino. I did not find any details about the data(model) layer. The same exists in Sproutcore. Am I missing something?

Comment: The title of this one is miss leading. I proposed a change because otherwise it looks like a duplicate of [SproutCore vs. Cappuccino](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287953/sproutcore-vs-cappuccino) although this one explicitly asks about details for the data layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SproutCore the model layer provides full object-relational mapping and manages things like storage, state, querying and back-end retrieval of the data. Cappuccino does not provide a model layer in the same sense, so from what I've seen (e.g. http://github.com/suitmymind/cappuccinocasts-episodes/tree/master/009) you would instead directly send requests to your back-end and then load the results into objects and handle state, querying, etc. yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Like bruz says, Cappuccino is probably more freeform at the data layer than SproutCore. That said, you could plug in Nicholas Small's [CPActiveRecord](http://github.com/nciagra/Cappuccino-Extensions/blob/master/CPActiveRecord.j) or Raphael Bartolome's [Core Data Cappuccino](http://github.com/rbartolome/CoreData-Cappuccino) to get a more automated model experience which also manages server connectivity in various ways.